# How to make this array + function to work?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, file

I need help with my array. I'm new on C# Winforms.

This is my function where the array is going, I'm trying to post the array on XML file:

```
    // ------------------- Functions
    static void XML_Array(string Data_Array)
    {
        String xmlfile = "/XMLFiles/Settings_Data.xml";

        XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlfile, Encoding.Unicode);

        xwriter.WriteStartDocument();

        xwriter.WriteStartElement("XMLFILE");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Data_Array)
        {
            String Element_Name = kvp.Key;
            String Element_Value = kvp.Value.ToString();

            xwriter.WriteStartElement(Element_Name);
            xwriter.WriteString(Element_Value);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
        }

        xwriter.WriteEndDocument();
        xwriter.Close();

    }
```

This is my array, here what I'm trying to do is when I press the button2 to send the array on my function, and the function to add the data of array on XML file

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Data_Array.Add("Name", "textBox3.Text"); // Alex
        Data_Array.Add("Year", "textBox4.Text"); // 1988

        XML_Array(Data_Array);
    }
```

### Update

How I can make if my array is

```
Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Data_Array.Add("Name", textBox3.Text); // Alex
Data_Array.Add("Year", textBox4.Text); // 1988

Data_Array.Add("Birthday", new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

And to Birthday to add Day, Month

Comment: Naming something "Array" takes away from the fact that it's a dictionary...

Comment: you should better rename your variables to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'll help you out with your next question -- `"textBox3.Text"` should likely be `textBox3.Text` (no quotes).

Comment: I'm also downvoting because the compiler should've told you exactly what was going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of the method to

```
static void XML_Array(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array)
```

since it's not a `string` but a `Dictionary`.

As varg and Austin have commented you should consider to rename your variables because it's confusing when an argument is names `Data_Array` but actually it is a `Dictionary` what is a completely different type of collection. You probably want to add the `Text` property of an existing `TextBox` control, not the string literal(with quotes) `"textBox3.Text"`.

```
Data_Array.Add("Name", textBox3.Text); // Alex
Data_Array.Add("Year", textBox4.Text); // 1988
```

`TextBox3` and `TextBox4` are also good candidates for new names.

Comment: According to your updated question: Assuming that the BirthDay(variable `bd` in following code) is stored as `DateTime` you can get the day and month as string in the following way: `dict.Add("BirthDay",string.Format("{0}-{1}",bd.Day,bd.Month));`. Apart from that consider to accept the answer if it works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work If you have further questions, ask new questions.