# problems with array and function and xml

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, winforms, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make this array + function to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168330/how-to-make-this-array-function-to-work)

This is my function, what I'm trying to do is to post the array on XML file. I'm new on this.

```
// ------------------- Functions
static void XML_Array(Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Data_Array)
    {
        if (kvp.Key == "XML_File")
        {
            String xmlfile = kvp.Value;
        }

        XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlfile, Encoding.Unicode);

        xwriter.WriteStartDocument();

        if (kvp.Key == "StartElement")
        {
            xwriter.WriteStartElement(kvp.Value);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp2 in Elements_Array)
        {
            String Element_Name = kvp2.Key;
            String Element_Value = kvp2.Value.ToString();

            xwriter.WriteStartElement(Element_Name);
            xwriter.WriteString(Element_Value);
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
        }

        xwriter.WriteEndDocument();
        xwriter.Close();
    }

}
```

My array code is this, when I press the button2 the array is going to the function

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Data_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Data_Array.Add("XML_File", "Settings_Data.xml");
        Data_Array.Add("StartElement", "XMLFILE");

        Dictionary<string, string> Elements_Array = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Elements_Array.Add("Name", textBox3.Text);
        Elements_Array.Add("Age", textBox4.Text);
        Elements_Array.Add("Gentle", comboBox6.SelectedIndex);

        Data_Array.Add("Elements_Array", Elements_Array);

        XML_Array(Data_Array);
    }
```

### Update

The problem is and of course the question is how I can make on function
where is String xmlfile = to show me the XML_File value = Settings_Data.xml.

And one more problem is `Data_Array.Add("Elements_Array", Elements_Array)`, I get error on this part.

Comment: any reason you're not using XDocument (LINQ)?

Comment: Sorry.. what is the actual problem? You've said what you want to do.. but you haven't said what your issue is.

Comment: Duplicate post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12168330/380384

Comment: not really is different question

Comment: READ THE COMPILER ERRORS. "I get error on this part".. it is very clear that you're attempting to add a `Dictionary<string, string>` as they value in a `Dictionary<string, string>`.. that's not going to work. The compiler WILL TELL YOU THIS. You said the exact same thing in @ja72's link.

Comment: i know is not going to work because this i ask the question i was hope someone can help me or tell me how to make this work ... if was working i didnt was asking ... true ?

Comment: this isn't really a different question. it's the same type. it seems you are stuck in the correct implementation of xml creation, because you are completely new to c#. do yourself a favor and read a little bit more on http://msdn.com or other resources to get background information on xml and c#.

Comment: Matei, for us to give you directions we need to know where you're trying to go. It is not clear from your question what you are trying to do; what kind of XML are you expecting? Please post an example. You say "i have many buttons...". How does that affect your question? You need to explain these things because we do not know what you are trying to do. Also, please make the effort to use correct grammar; your update is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Why even bother with the dictionary phase?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XDocument doc = new XDocument()
        XElement root = new XElement("XML_File");
        root.Add(new XElement("name",textBox3.text));

        ... blah blah

}
```

Comment: i bother because i have many buttons and every button have his own xml file and i want just to make one function to make what need to be done ... i know how to make it on php but is not disame on c# winforms

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements then it is possible that this is all you need:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = new XDocument(new XElement("XMLFILE", new []
    {
        new XElement("Name", textBox3.Text),
        new XElement("Age", textBox4.Text),
        new XElement("Gentle", comboBox6.SelectedIndex),
    }));

    XML_Array("Settings_Data.xml", data);
}
```

And then have this:

```
static void XML_Array(string fileName, XDocument data)
{
    data.Save(fileName);
}
```

The file that results from this code would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLFILE>
  <Name>James</Name>
  <Age>42</Age>
  <Gentle>1</Gentle>
</XMLFILE>
```